# Concatenate Series in pandas throwing away overlapping indexes

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

Suppose I have the following three Series with overlapping indexes

```
s1 = pd.Series(data=np.arange(5))
s2 = pd.Series(data=np.arange(5),index=np.arange(2,7))
s3 = pd.Series(data=np.arange(5),index=np.arange(5,10))
```

I wish concatenate them into one series; however, I wish to have the data values in ovelapping indexes taken from the series which has the "latest" index.

Hence in the toy case the output would be:

```
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    0
6    1
7    2
8    3
9    4
dtype: int32
```

This could also be viewed as cutting each series at the point it has overlap with the next series and then just concatenating. Is there a fast and efficient way to do this in `pandas` when there could be many series of large length.

**EDIT**

I am looking for an *efficient* way to do this as in reality both the length and the number of Series is large, around 100k and 10k respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is use `concatenate` for flatten indices and values of `Series` and filter by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with inverted mask by `~`:

```
def new1(series):
    b = [x.index for x in series]
    v = np.concatenate(series)
    i = np.concatenate(b)

    mask = ~pd.Series(i).duplicated(keep='last')
    return pd.Series(v[mask], index=i[mask])
```

Comment: This seems like it works efficiently. As it returns a numpy array is there anyway to keep track of which index each data point from?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest that I can suggest is the following:

```
series = [s1, s2, s3]
s = pd.concat(series)
your_series = s[(~s.index[::-1].duplicated())[::-1]]
```

You can compare the times:

```
import functools

def method1(series):
    s = pd.concat(series)
    return s[(~s.index[::-1].duplicated())[::-1]]

def method2(series):
    s1,s2,s3 = series
    return functools.reduce(pd.Series.combine_first, [s3,s2,s1])

def method3(series):
    s1,s2,s3 = series
    listc = s3.append(s2).append(s1).reset_index().drop_duplicates(
        subset='index', keep='first').set_index('index').sort_index()
    return listc

def method4(series):
    return pd.DataFrame(series).ffill().tail(1).T
```

Results:

```
>>> %timeit method1(series)
... 643 µs ± 25.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit method2(series)
... 1.15 ms ± 26.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit method3(series)
... 3.09 ms ± 262 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit method4(series)
... 1.07 ms ± 16.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Of course the memory implications of these approaches might be worth considering when applying to a larger dataset.

---

**EDIT:**

A small test on much larger series:

```
series = [pd.Series(data=np.arange(100000), index=np.arange(i*5000,100000+i*5000)) for i in range(100)]
```

Result:

```
>>> %timeit method1(series)
... 583 ms ± 18.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit method2(series)
... 4.5 s ± 25.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

However, when the number of series is smaller but the size of each series is larger then the difference is much less:

```
series = [pd.Series(data=np.arange(1000000), index=np.arange(i*5000,1000000+i*5000)) for i in range(10)]
```

Result:

```
>>> %timeit method1(series)
... 679 ms ± 23.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit method2(series)
... 1.39 s ± 26.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

For anything much larger than this though you might want to consider a different approach like map-reduce as a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
# create a dataframe with all series
df = pd.DataFrame({'s1':s1, 's2':s2, 's3': s3})

# ffill for the latest index:
df.ffill(1)
```

Output (your expected is the last column):

```
      s1    s2    s3
--  ----  ----  ----
 0     0     0     0
 1     1     1     1
 2     2     0     0
 3     3     1     1
 4     4     2     2
 5   nan     3     0
 6   nan     4     1
 7   nan   nan     2
 8   nan   nan     3
 9   nan   nan     4
```

One liner:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([s1,s2,s3]).ffill().tail(1).T
```

Output:

```
      2
--  ---
 0    0
 1    1
 2    0
 3    1
 4    2
 5    0
 6    1
 7    2
 8    3
 9    4
```

Comment: This method is incredibly slow when the number of series is large

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Let me know:

```
listc = s3.append(s2).append(s1).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='index', keep='first').set_index('index').sort_index()
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution when the number of series is large

Answer (score 0):

With `functools.reduce` and `pd.Series.combine_first`

```
import functools

functools.reduce(pd.Series.combine_first,[s3,s2,s1])
Out[794]: 
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    0.0
6    1.0
7    2.0
8    3.0
9    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This method is slow when the number of series is large